# Simulate expansion of smoke in NetLogo

Tags: simulation, netlogo

I am trying to simulate the expansion of smoke inside an area in NetLogo but I have some difficulties. Initially, I created turtles with a "cloud" shape to simulate the smoke. I want every random intervals to "hatch" a "cloud" shape turtle. The turtles must hatch next to another "cloud" turtle in order to simulate the expansion of smoke. Also, I have to make the "clouds" a bit transparent in order to be able to see if an agent enters the smoke. Thank you very much!

```
to create-danger
  ;; based on a slider, create the number of cloud turtles
  create-smoke number-of-dangers
  [
    ;;create smoke only inside a specific area
    while[ [pcolor] of patch-here != FLOOR-COLOUR]
    [
      ;;creates random coordinates
      rand-xy-co
    ]
  ]
end
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwqrJ.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of different ways to expand the smoke, depending on how much space is meant by 'next to'. Let's say you want it to be 0.2 spatial units away, then you can simply have the parent cloud turtle do something like `hatch 1 [set heading random 360 forward 0.2]`. The [] immediately after the `hatch` are instructions that the child turtle runs as soon as it is created. It will be hatched with the same heading as its parent, so you need to randomise that and then have it move the appropriate distance.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works! The only issue that I have is that after sometime the simulation slows down. Should I do something else about the expansion?

Comment: How many clouds do you have? NetLogo should not obviously slow unless you have thousands. You can get thousands if you have them multiplying very quickly, but you may want to think about what you are trying to represent. Real smoke expands but the 'old' clouds die off because all their smoke is in the new clouds.

Comment: The issue was that I was expanding the cloud very fast and as a result the whole simulation got slower. I do not want to "kill" the old smoke because I assume that I have a constant area that produces smoke. Thanks to you I could solve my problem!!! Thank you very much for your help!!!